# I have a footer that is set to position absolute. Is there a better way to resize it as the window resizes?

Tags: html, css

I'm making a website and my  is set to position absolute so that it always stays on the very bottom of the page. I want it to shrink with the rest of the elements on the page so that it is always a few pixels away from the closest element to the bottom.

```
footer{
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;

padding: 3%;
padding-left: 10%;
padding-right: 10%;

background-color: #f9f1f1;
}
```

I'm putting padding-bottom on the  so that the footer doesn't come into contact with other elements on the page. In the past, I've used media queries to add more padding to the main as the page decreases in width, but this gets very tedious as I have to make a new query for every new 50px of width difference. I'm sure that there is a better way of doing this, but I can't find what it would be. Any suggestions? I'm open to other ways of making flexible and responsive footers that always stay on the bottom of the page.

Comment: That is a commonly asked CSS question to which you find many topics such as here: https://css-tricks.com/couple-takes-sticky-footer/